# IOException: closed failed on FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android, sdk, fileoutputstream

For my app, I'm copying files from a Source to a Destination folder for further image processing. I'm
Trying to copy a jpg file from the src to the dst folder. The
function seems to work, but I'm still getting this IOException error. 
Could anyone shed some light on why close() would be failing?

```
 public static void copyPicture(String src, String dst) {

   File pic = null;
   File newPic = null;

pic = new File(src);
newPic = new File(dst);

FileChannel srcChannel = null;
FileChannel dstChannel = null;

try {
srcChannel = new FileInputStream(pic).getChannel();
dstChannel = new FileOutputStream(newPic).getChannel();

dstChannel.transferFrom(srcChannel, 0, srcChannel.size());



} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {

    try {

    if(dstChannel != null) {
        dstChannel.close();
    }
        srcChannel.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    srcChannel = null;
    dstChannel = null;

    src = null;
    dst = null;
 }

 }
```

Catlog:

```
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070): java.io.IOException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070): at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:41)
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070): at     java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:139)
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070):    at  java.io.FileOutputStream.finalize(FileOutputStream.java:153)
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:186)
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070):    at  java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: close  failed: EIO (I/O error)
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070):    at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070):    at   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
07-04 21:43:15.330: E/System(28070):    at  libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:38)
```

Comment: Whats the name of your class? I never used FileChannel but maybe you need to close the Streams, too.

Comment: I'm already closing it? dstChannel.close();

Answer (score 0):

Since the `FileChannel` cache data I think you need to call [force()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#force%28boolean%29) before you `close()` the `FileChannel`.

Comment: I dont see why it would work, but I tested it of course, to no avail :)

Comment: I figured if its empty you might be able to close it, but it was a long shot since I did not test it myself. In fact I am not able to reproduce the problem. I should say that I only tested it as a regular Java application since I do not have access to my Android environment ATM.

Comment: Still get the same exception,  really frustrating :) thanks for all help